# Multiple Instances of Same War file in Single Server

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat 6.0 Application server and Apache HTTP webserver 2.2 and Eclipse Galileo as my IDE. I developed an web application which is some site where users can login and browse around it. My problem is Only one user can access the application.

That is when an user is logged in he can use it well, If another user attempt to login at the same time the application changes to the data of the recent user logged in. How do i configure my Tomcat or Apache to use the application independently for large number(atmost 4 to 7) of users. I dunno i made myself clear or not..

But to be more clear, To post anything in daniweb.com we login by username and password.. At the same time some other person might have logged in. How to do this.?? This is my problem.

Thanks in Advance

Sathyan S

Comment: Um, this does not seam to be a Tomcat configuration issue. Looks like a major application design problem. Tomcat itself does provide concurrent user support. Please further desribe your problem and/or attach some code!

Comment: Thanx for the reply..

Assume I have a login page and one welcome page.. when i enter the username and password i store my username in a static variable.. i access that static variale from other classes to identify which user has logged in and to provide details.. This is the logic i used.. When the second user logs in the the static variable in the login page is overwrited..

Regards 
Sathyan S

Comment: @home: you are right.. It was a poor design.. I think i should not use the static variables.. Instead i need to use Session variables.. Bad Programing method.. :( :( :( 

Anyway Thanx for the Reply.. Good day.. :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work. A static variable can have only one value at a time (per JVM and Classloader). If I correctly understand your issue, you have to store this information in the `HttpSession`, which you can retrieve from the `HttpServletRequest`: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean).